# Displaying progress indicator inside an NSSearchField

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nssearchfield

I am using a NSSearchField to run a query over the internet and display the results in a table view. Whilst the query is running I would like to display a progress indicator inside an NSSearchField? I think I have seen this done in another application before.

Is there an open source component that I could use to accomplish this?

How would I go about doing this? What is the best way? What are the pitfalls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to put the progress indicator above (atop) the search field and leave them as separate views. It used to be that view z-ordering would give unpredictable results and weren't encouraged. That's not been true for several OS X versions, now, so if it looks good and behaves as expected, I say go for it.

The harder way would be to subclass NSSearchField and muck around according to the goodies found in the [Control and Cell Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ControlCell/ControlCell.html) for Cocoa guide.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a custom subclass of UISearchFieldCell. Find the method that draws the background and try to add your custom drawing code there. I'd rather not fiddle with nested components. I think the one used in safari is also a custom control.

Answer (score 0):

This is not my solution but I came across this question and I eventually found someone that worked out a solution and it worked for me:

https://github.com/owainhunt/UAShared/blob/master/UAShared/NSSearchField%2BSpinner.m